# Ignore input method input in AWT Component on Mac

Tags: java, swing, awt, ime

On Mac, the US International PC keyboard layout has dead keys for several keys such as `"`, `'` and backtick. When typing `"`, the Mac starts input method composition - the `"` shown in compose mode (usually underlined) and waits for further input. If I use `a`, then the input method will complete and I'll get the character `ä`. There are several such dead keys, and e.g. the British keyboard layout treats <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> as a dead key to give something like `ñ`.

In a Java AWT application, is there any way I can disable this behaviour so that I get simply the raw keys typed? E.g. in the US International PC keyboard layout, if I type <kbd>"</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, I want to receive events for `"` and `a`, and not one event for `ä`. In the British keyboard layout, I want to type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> and receive events for `Alt+n` and `n` and not `ñ`.

If I call `Component.enableInputMethods(false)`, then my event queue will receive the `Alt+n` event, but if I then follow with <kbd>n</kbd>, I receive `ñ`.

Similarly, if I use a Chinese keyboard layout, the popup input method is still active, even after calling `Component.enableInputMethods(false)`.

Is there any way to completely disable input method processing, and receive just the keys, as typed?

For context, I'm trying to implement Vim like behaviour - normal mode editing requires ASCII input, while insert mode will of course handle input methods as expected. While it would be ideal to swap to an ASCII keyboard layout in normal mode, but even the Mac's "ABC" keyboard layout has dead keys for `Alt+n`, `Alt+u`, `Alt+I` and `Alt+e` and `Alt+Backtick`. Telling users to create a custom keyboard layout with something like [Ukulele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/) is not a viable option.

Comment: Yes, a custom component that extends `JTextComponent`.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Have you explored the object returned by method [getInputContext()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getInputContext--) in class `java.awt.Component`?

Comment: Yes. I can't get anything useful out of it.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: Sadly no. I don't know how to do this, but would still like to know